# Making input to select

Tags: php, list, select, input, opencart

I'm trying to make auto dropdown list with quantity of products.

okay, that's problem (cms - opencart)
I have In default input to write product qnt:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>" />
```

$minimum is that you set when uploading product.

I want to make dropdown list with options.
Now I'm trying to change to select, and thats my code:

```
        <select name="quantity">
  <?php foreach ($discounts as $discount) { ?>

        <option name="quantity" value="<?php $discount['quantity']; ?>"><?php echo sprintf($text_discount, $discount['quantity'], $discount['price']); ?></option><br />

  <?php } ?>
  </select>
```

okay thats good in preview, I'm get my select list, but then customer select one from the list, It not quanty for product, always all options set to = 1.

In prieview text $discount['quantity'] show correctly number, but not set to value.. Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set the attribute "name" to the option tag. This might be the issue. And there is also no need for the br tag after each option. It should look like this:

```
<select name="quantity">
<?php foreach ($discounts as $discount) { ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $discount['quantity']; ?>"><?php echo sprintf($text_discount, $discount['quantity'], $discount['price']); ?></option>

<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but this is not working :/
Now option set not 1 like default, but 0

Comment: Now it works! THanks! Just changed
<option value="<?php $discount['quantity']; ?>
to
<option value="<?php echo $discount['quantity']; ?>